# How can I debug a Codeigniter Cron job that only runs the default controller and action when called?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface

I am running a new site on Codeigniter 2.1.0 and have configured the following Cron job:

```
php -q /home/overstoc/www/admin/index.php  cron update
```

The output sent to me shows that only the default controller and default action are being called. Any parameters being sent are ignored.

Any suggestions on the way to debug this or a known bug that causes this problem?

---

Logging onto the server I am able to successfully load the desired controllers and action manually through SSH. However, the Cron job is not passing the requested parameters.

Comment: Did u try running it manually from browser

Comment: Yes, I can successfully call any of the actions in the cron controller when I use the browser.

Comment: A lot of times you'll see people use calls to text browsers like Lynx to just have it run as a simple page request instead of a CLI code.

Comment: I have previously utilized wget and curl to achieve the end result, but after some recent events I need to make it more secure and protected. I know I could restrict just to the local server in the scripting, but I want this to work. I was able to do it fine with a test Kohana site, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further researching I was able to determine that there are two modes to php running: cgi or cli. Upon testing with `php -v` in shell I confirmed it was configured for cli, but running the same with a Cron job I saw the result being php running as cgi.

To resolve this I reconfigured my Cron job as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/overstoc/www/admin/index.php cron update
```

I assume the default php that the Cron job is calling has a configuration for cgi where the server share is cli.

Comment: Can anyone detail where the php that is called by default is located and why it would runs as cgi? Also, why does this differ from calling php in shell?